# How can I exit with non-zero when apache camel exits due to setDuration

Tags: apache-camel

I want to exit with non-zero exit code when camel job exits due to exceeding the duration that gets set with setDuration() method.

I tested it exits with a zero exit code that does not help me with determining if the process exited because it succeeded or due to exceeding max duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you refer to the java main class where you can tell it to run for 60 seconds as duration?

To exit with some other exit code, it would require a enhancement in the Apache Camel source. You can log a ticket at: http://camel.apache.org/support.html